# Pydantic: Type hinting tensorflow tensor

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, type-hinting, pydantic

any idea of how to type-hint tf tensors using pydantic??. Tried default tf.Tensor

```
RuntimeError: no validator found for <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>, see `arbitrary_types_allowed` in Config
```

and tf.flaot32

```
RuntimeError: error checking inheritance of tf.float32 (type: DType)
```

Looking at documentation in pydantic, i believe something like this arbitrary class need to be defined...

```
class Tensor:
    def __init__(self, Tensor):

        self.Tensor = Union[
            tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor,
            tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor,
            tensorflow.python.ops.ragged.ragged_tensor.RaggedTensor,
            tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor,
        ]
```

with following in main..

```
 class Main(BaseModel):
     tensor : Tensor


 class Config:
    arbitary_types_allowed = True
```

Comment: Please explain the context of what you are trying to do. How do you intend to use this class? How did you get those errors?

Answer (score 0):

working code:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
import tensorflow as tf


class MyTensor(BaseModel):

    tensor: tf.Variable

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
```